# Hide decimal places upto 2 places like excel not delete in php when value is set by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.5 making a Costing Sheet where i calculate values by using javascript function, which give value in decimal places, and if i round the value then there is different in total for exact amount,
 So i want to show value set by javascript upto only 2 decimal but want to save all decimal values into database i.e. MySql ,

```
    <td colspan="2" >
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Particular.particular_value'.$i,  array('name'=>'particular_value[]','label'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'number','min'=>'0','step'=>'.001','default' => "0",'autocomplete' => 'off','value'=>isset($this->data['Particular'][$index]['particular_bare_pipe_rate_per_mt_value'])?$this->data['Particular'][$index]['particular_bare_pipe_rate_per_mt_value'] :'0')); ?>
    </td>
```

and

```
$('#CostValue').val(precisionRound(pbcrv, 0));
function precisionRound(number, precision) {
        var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
        return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
    }
```

when i input values then it calculate by predefined formulas i round them using precisionRound function , but when i make total it always vary from total that is made by excel sheet,
I want something like EXCEL sheet number function, where i show value upto 2 decimal on front for showing but when i calculate or save values in to database it should be saved with all decimal values.

[image: Calculation table]

Blue background input boxes are input boxes which are calling js function for further calculation, grey background input boxes are disabled for input (they are based on first inputs) is place where i want to display 2 decimal place value.
 Like that--

- Actual Value - 2664.267779
- show Value on front - 2664
- Save in database - 2664.267779

Comment: So you want to display a value cut down to 2 decimal but when it comes to using it to calculate something you want to use the full integer? If so then why not save the original version but only round it down to 2 decimal for viewing.... when it comes to using that value you can use the one saved to return a accurate result.... If you could provide some sort of example that might make things easier for me to provide you with an example/solution.

Comment: you can create input field with rounded value and after that create <input type="hidden"> and set it's value to actual value. When you need to do calculation you can just use value stored in hidden input

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I can think of many ways of getting a good/true output but without knowing when this calculation should be taking place makes it hard to offer a good solution. You could save on using hidden inputs and use a `data-` attribute to hold the true/full value so all information on that item is contained in one element rather than creating 2 elements for one value and hiding one.

Comment: @NewToJS i have updated question, i am making a costing sheet for pipes where input are not predefined, there may be many pipe sizes , on which i have to calculate total Cost price

Answer (score 0):

For a number of reasons you should consider not relying on the client side calculations to POST the data to the server and then store it.  A more robust solution would be to POST the inputs to the calculation and do the calculation again on the server.

The reasons for this are many, e.g.

a) An error in your client side calcs could easily see NaN posted to the server in error.

b) If this calculation was (for example) calculating a total price for X items of the same type that you were ordering and showing the total, a canny user would be able to edit the input field prior to posting and possibly pay a smaller amount for their goods.

---

For those that read (b) and think 'naw - no-one would do that', I have seen it in the wild...

Comment: i have to show calculation on client side                                                                     For a). i have restricted user to enter other character than number or else it will take 0 as input, For b)it is not same type of calculation, it is basically a costing sheet, where multiple rates are applying.